# Python regex by grouping elements belonging to same category

Tags: python, regex

I have a file like this:

```
<table>
<span clas="city"> Miami </span> <span><a href="miami" > Miami </a> </span>
<span clas="city"> Orlando </span> <span><a href="orlando" > orlando </a></span>
</table>
<table>
<span clas="city"> Los Angeles </span> <span><a href="Los Angeles" > </a> </span>
<span clas="city"> San Diego </span>  <span><a href="Los Angeles" > San Diego</a> </span>
</table>
```

How can I extend this regex `re.compile('city">([^<]+)</span>')` to group cities belonging to same state(table) when a table ends (without a while loop), such as

```
State 1: Miami, Orlando
State 2: Los Angeles, San Diego
```

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1561176

Comment: Why are you using regex to do that work ?
"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski
Just use lxml with html, there are tons of tutos on web for that kind of stuff and you won't go crazy ^^

Comment: @Inbar well that took me a while, and I figured myself. I am able to get cities, but I was wondering if there is a neat way of categorizing.

Comment: If you really want to use regexes, then use two regexes: one to find the tables, then one to search for the cities within each text inside the <table> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper HTML parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(...).read())
states = {}
for i, table in enumerate(soup("table")):
    for city in table("span"):
        states.setdefault(i, []).append(city.text.strip())
```

which will give

```
states
{0: [u'Miami', u'Orlando'], 1: [u'Los Angeles', u'San Diego']}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was gonna accept this answer, but I saw for some tables I am getting duplicates as some rows have multiple <span>s. I updated the table structure.

Comment: Use `table("span", "city")` to search for only the `span` tags that have class `city`. You should read the docs for BeautifulSoup.